# How to exclude 0 from MIN formula unless that is the only option?

Tags: excel

I want excel to select the lowest number excluding 0 from the D and G Columns and display it in the H Column. Right now my table looks like this:

```
   A   B    C     D    E    F   G     H
1  1 150.00 52 7800.00 0 569.99 0.00  =SMALL((G5,J5),INDEX(FREQUENCY((D1,G1),0),1)+1)
2  0  50.00 52    0.00 0 750.00 0.00  =SMALL((G5,J5),INDEX(FREQUENCY((D2,G2),0),1)+1)
```

Row 1 works as expected and selects 7800.00 and ignores the 0, but for row 2 selects neither because they're both 0 and displays #NUM!. Any chance that I can fix this?

Comment: Thank you sir that works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

As Mr SeanC said it was as easy as just using =IFERROR:

`=IFERROR(SMALL((G5,J5),INDEX(FREQUENCY((D2,G2),0),1)+1),0)`